# Pod Install , React Native Pod installation fails

Tags: react-native, rubygems

I am trying to install the pods in my react native project but it is giving me the error on Macbook Air Apple M2 2022 model. (see the screenshot)

But if i am trying to install the pods in my older Macbook Pro then it is working fine and install the pods successfully.

I need help regarding that issue because i can not work on old laptop due to its slow processing power.
[image]

Comment: Go to your project root and try ```npx pod-install```

Comment: You don't have cocoapods installed - `gem install cocoapods`. Also please add your error as text and not as an image